# Can't add server to Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I just set up a dynamic web project that uses JSP in Eclipse and now I'm trying to add a server to run the project on. I go to add a new server in the server view and I have no option to select "next" or "finish" no matter what server type I select. Both Tomcat 9.0 and Glassfish are installed. 
[image]

Comment: Are there any more details you can give? Is anything in the error log for this?

Comment: @nitind I'm not sure what more info I could possibly give. There's no error log because I cannot run the project without a server of course.